# Deploying to multiple EC2 servers with Fabric

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, fabric

I'm wondering if anyone has experience deploying to multiple servers behind a load balancer on ec2 with [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/index.html)

I have used fabric for a while now, and have no issues with it, or deploying to multiple servers, but what I would like to do in this scenario is (lets say I have ten instances running) de-register half (5) of the boxes from my load balancer, deploy my code to them and run a smoke test, and if everything looks good, register them with the load balancer again and de-register the remaining 5 instances and deploy to them, and then register them back to the load balancer.

I have no problem accomplishing any of the individual tasks (de-registering, running tests, deploying etc),   I just don't know how to organize my hosts in a simple fashion so that I can deploy the first half, then the second half. Fabric seems to be set up to run the same tasks on all hosts in order (task 1 on host 1, task 1 on host 2, task 2 on host 1, task 2 on host 2 etc etc)

My first thought was to create a task to handle the first part of de-registering, deploying and testing, and then set the env.hosts for the second half of the servers,  but i felt this seemed a bit hokey.

Has anyone modeled something similar to this with Fabric before?

Comment: From my limited experience with Fabric, that sounds like exactly what you'd want to do. The only way I'd think it was hokey is if you wanted to do some type of random selection of the 5 boxes.

Comment: As an alternative, `ansible` does something like this out of the box. Worth a look: http://docs.ansible.com/guide_rolling_upgrade.html#the-rolling-upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simplify this by defining **roles** (used for aggregation of hosts) and executing your tasks on one role, then running tests and deploying on the second role.

Example of `roledefs`:

```
env.roledefs = {
    'first_half': ['host1', 'host2'],
    'second_half': ['host3', 'host4'],
}

def deploy_server():
    ...
    # deploy one host from current role here

def deploy():
    # first role:
    env.roles = ['first_half']
    execute('deploy_server')
    test()  # here test deployed servers
    # second role:
    env.roles = ['second_half']
    execute('deploy_server')
```

More links:

- [`env.roledefs` documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/env.html#roledefs),
- [`env.roles` documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/env.html#roles),
- [execution model](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html),
- [`execute()` documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute),

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you use `execute` vs calling `deploy_server` directly

Comment: Also, you're using execute wrong there. You give it a task as a passed function, not a string with it's name. That and execute can take roles: execute(deploy_server, roles=['first_half'])

Comment: @Morgan: Incorrect. Please take a look at the documentation link I originally included in the answer. `execute` accepts both callable and task name (string). You are however right about the ability to set the roles it should be executed on (also see this in docs).

Comment: @MattoTodd: I believe this way is preferred by Fabric documentation. It respects `hosts` and `roles` decorators and was specifically designed to serve the purpose of executing tasks as if they were invoked from command line. In other words: Fabric and `execute` were designedthat way.

Comment: @Tadeck correct, it does accept both. But if you look at any examples, all use callables. Which I find cleaner, more pythonic, and I also tend to find more flexible. It's good to get in the mindset of using functions over strings in fabric, since other parts take them, eg:roldefs/hosts, and will evaluate them lazily.

Comment: @Morgan: So basically "_you're using execute wrong there_" is incorrect - one could use both string and callable, but you personally prefer callable, as shown in the Fabric documentation (actually only in one place, in two-line example here: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute)

Comment: @Tadeck well that and (nearly) every use of execute() inside of the Fabric code itself uses it the way I recommend. Barring the one time it's used as you suggested to test that strings work. It's also better to use callables since as the docs say, those lookups will only work if the value of the sting is a function decorated as a task. So if you're only ever wanting to execute() on \@task'd funcitons strings instead of callables work just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [execute()](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) function. This will allow you to do something like this:

```
def update():
     deallocate()
     push_code()
     smoke_test() #could fail fast
     reallocate()

def deploy():
     execute(update, hosts=first_five)
     execute(update, hosts=last_five)
```

You could also make each of the deallocate, push_code, and smoke_test, tasks an execute() call in the deploy, and then you'd run all the deallocates then run all the code pushes, etc.

Then have a check of some sort and then proceed with the others running said tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully combined Fabric with boto.  I populate the hosts list using boto.  You can use the @parallel decorator to limit the number of hosts to execute in one go.  The command looks as follows;

`fab running deploy`

The code looks like so;

```
@task
@runs_once
def running():
    ec2conn = ec2.connect_to_region(region)
    reservations = ec2conn.get_all_instances(filters={'instance-state-name': 'running'})
    instances = list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda r: r.instances, reservations)))
    env.hosts = list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda i: i.public_dns_name, instances)))

@task
@parallel(pool_size=5)
def deploy():
    # do stuff on n<=5 hosts in parallel
```

If you need to handle a subsection of hosts I'd suggest using tags.

Comment: random note: you have to be careful not to re-use the same ec2 connection object in parallel tasks, as boto is not thread safe (it's sort of an epistemological question whether any given python library is "thread safe", but what I mean is that boto is known to break when used this way)

Answer (score 0):

Fabric is not set-up to run the same tasks on all hosts.

Apart from the fact that you can explicitly set the hosts for a specific
task with the `-H` command line parameter, you can use [this](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#globally-via-env) pattern and
[this](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#roles) newer pattern to do exactly what you want.

Update: [Here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.1/usage/execution.html#intelligently-executing-tasks-with-execute) it shows how you can use `roles`

Comment: since fabric uses env.hosts by default, how do you specify a particular role in one of your tasks?

Comment: You're welcome! Although I had to resort to google for translating what you said :D

Comment: can you call the same task with different roles?

Comment: use execute(), see answer I use to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply write a method which sets some variables, for example:

```
def live():
    global PATH, ENV_PATH
    env.hosts = ["22.2.222.2"]
    env.user = 'test'
    PATH = '/path/to/project'
    # optional, is using virtualenv
    ENV_PATH = '/path/to/virtualenv'
    # overwri
```

te whatever variabled you need to change on the current machine

and before running the deploy command, run:

```
fab live deploy
```

Details: http://simionbaws.ro/programming/deploy-with-fabric-on-multiple-servers/

Answer (score -1):

Rather than meddle with env.hosts, you could pass a list (or any iterable) to the hosts decorator. Something like:

```
def deploy(half_my_hosts):
    @hosts(half_my_hosts)
    def mytask():
        # ...
    mytask()
```

Then you could split your env.hosts in any way you like and pass it to deploy()

Comment: there is now execute() for subtasks and has a hosts param.

Comment: Ah, thanks, good to know. That's certainly a cleaner solution.